# Overlay multiple image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to overlay multiple image maintaining pixel intensity. I am trying to overlay based on the following documentation,
https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-blend-multiple-images-using-opencv/

I tried following to overlay two frame together using following,

```
dst1 = cv2.addWeighted(img1, 1, img2, 1,  0)
```

It produces expected output with 2 frame,
But if tried to overlay with multiple frame using following program(based on above documentation)

```
first_img = list_[0]
for img in range(len(list_)):
   if img ==0:
       pass
   else:
       alpha = 1/(len(list_)+1)
       beta = 1-alpha
       dts = cv2.addWeighted(first_img,alpha,list_[img],beta,0)
```

But it produced following error

```
Overload resolution failed:src1 is not a numpy array 
neither a scalarExpected Ptrcv::UMat for argument ‘src1’
```

Array of image is loaded from the folder using the following program,

```
def read_img(img_list, img):
    n = cv2.imread(img, 0)
    img_list.append(n)
    return img_list
path = glob.glob("*.jpg")
list_ = []
cv_image = [read_img(list_, img) for img in path]
```

[image: Img01][image: Img02]

Comment: Are you really using jpegs as your input images? These look like heatmaps that you're converting to RGB. If that's the case, it would be much simpler to take the max of the single-channel images. Why are you using `np.hstack` after merging the images? Is your result image `dst1` or `img_arr`? Because it's not what I would expect from either based on the input images you gave.

Comment: Yes, currently I am using jpeg for input image. I want to use it to overlay multiple image. The resulting image is from dst1. The purpose is to look for the intensity of event in the location.

Comment: How do you define "intensity"?

Comment: increasing intensity of color with every events detected at that position, similar to 2D histogram

Comment: That's not very mathematically precise. What formula would you use to determine the intensity of a given pixel in your image?

Comment: This post is not very clear and might be closed if not clarified. Please show more code for what you want. Your two commands are totally independent. Also please identify your images. Is one the desired output or your resulting output or are both input images?

Comment: To be more specific, is intensity determined by color (i.e. blue is lower intensity than red), or is it determined by the (weighted) sum of the RGB value, or maybe something else?

Comment: it is determined by color (blue having lower intensity than Red). I am new to opencv, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case you would have to know the mapping from each RGB value to intensity value. Alternatively, if somewhere in the creation of these images you have an intensity image that was later mapped to RGB values and saved as a jpeg, it would be **much**  simpler to just use the original intensity image.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance, I am currently working on overlaying original images which I could convert to heat-map. I will update once I am done.

Comment: I tried overlaying the multiple original frame using the following documentation
[Documentation link][1]]

but it gave me the following error

    Overload resolution failed:src1 is not a numpy array
    neither a scalarExpected Ptrcv::UMat for argument ‘src1’




  [1]: https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-blend-multiple-images-using-opencv/

Comment: We have no idea what you're starting with and what you're trying to achieve. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Hey I have re-ordered my question, but have not received any reply. @beaker could you please look into it once.

Comment: You have not received a reply because your question is incomplete. You have not included the calling code that sets up `list_`, which according to the error does not contain images. Furthermore, you have not included the input images so that someone could reproduce your results, nor have you identified your expected results to verify a potential solution against.

Comment: I should also note that you are overwriting `dts` on each pass through the loop, which I don't believe is your intent.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error with your code.